# htaccess mod_rewrite and 301 redirect to friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo, friendly-url

Now, I'm trying to write some htaccess code with mod_rewrite. I have problem with it :(

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?page=home
```

This is my code in .htaccess file. When I go to domena.com/index.php?page=home it's exactly same like domena.com/home

But, It's not friendly for google, 'cos we have double page:

```
domena.com/index.php?page=home
domena.com/home
```

It's same.

What I want to achieve? I want to user who choose domena.com/index.php?page=home redirect him to domena.com/home

Exactly, I want to on my website be exist ONLY friendly link.

Help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need another rule to redirect old URL to new one.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php?page=home [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Are you entering URL as `domena.com/index.php?page=home`? Where is this htaccess located?

Comment: Yes, I was entered this. I'm using xampp and htacces is located in localhost/folder/www/.htaccess

Comment: This is working and tested rule. Make sure it is placed in root .htaccess where .htaccess and index.php are located together.